# Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got DataFrame)

Tags: python, tokenize, text-mining

Hello I am new at python and I am not really familiar with python. I am trying to tokenize my data. I have 1000 customers reviews and I created a table called: review_table. I wrote the following code and wanted to see if it works:

```
review_table["exemple"] = [[sent for sent in doc.sents] for doc in 
review_table["spacy"]]
exemple = review_table["exemple"].iloc[0]
doc = nlp(review_table)

#strings are encoded to hashes
tokens = [token.text for token in doc]

print(exemple,'\n')
print(tokens)
```

But I got the following message error: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got DataFrame)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using pandas DataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes at the last line from the following snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
review_table = pd.DataFrame({'spacy':[nlp('I know it is cool.'),nlp('How are you?')]})
review_table["exemple"] = [[sent for sent in doc.sents] for doc in review_table["spacy"]]
exemple = review_table["exemple"].iloc[0]
doc = nlp(review_table)
```

It happens so because the `review_table` is a dataframe object with at least two columns, `spacy` (with spacy document objects) and `exemples` (with lists of spacy document objects).

You need to make sure you are not storing spacy documents in one of the columns. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import spacy
review_table = pd.DataFrame({'text':['I know it is cool.','How are you?']})
review_table['spacy'] = review_table['text'].apply(lambda x: [t.text for t in nlp(x)])
>>> review_table
#                  text                       spacy
# 0  I know it is cool.  [I, know, it, is, cool, .]
# 1        How are you?          [How, are, you, ?]
```

If you want to filter out stopwords:

```py
review_table['spacy'] = review_table['text'].apply(lambda x: [t.text for t in nlp(x) if not t.is_stop])
```

If you want to also remove punctuation:

```py
review_table['spacy'] = review_table['text'].apply(lambda x: [t.text for t in nlp(x) if not t.is_stop and not t.is_punct])
```